# How to stop handler.postDelayed in for-loop?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, handler, runnable

I saw no real answer for this type of using "handler.posDelayed".

So, I execute "handler.posDelayed" multiple times with a for-loop. The problem is, when I leave the activity and restart it, the new objects AND the old ones from the handler are executed too. I don't know, how to stop the old objects from the handler.

```
        private Handler handler = new Handler();

        private void startHandler() {

            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable); // DOESN'T WORK

            long time = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, time + i);
            }
        }

        private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Some code..
            }
        };
```

Comment: are you calling `removeCallbacksAndMessages` in on `onPause` / `onStop` / `onDestroy` ?

Comment: Currently only in the "startHandler" method. The method is called when I start the activity, so it doesn't matter I think. I think the problem is, that the loop creates multiple runnables.@pskink

Comment: there is only one Runnable, it is not duplicated

Comment: Okay. But I'm calling `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable);` at the start of the activity, also if it's restarted. So why it doesn't work?

Comment: it works, you most likely have "old" Runnables from "old" Activity that are not removed in onPause / onStop / onDestroy

Comment: btw shouldn't you call `removeCallbacks` , not `removeCallbacksAndMessages` ?

Comment: You are right with `removeCallback`. I tried `onStop` and `onDestroy` and it works now! Thank you! If you write an answer I'll mark it as correct. :)

Comment: but removeCallbacksAndMessages in onStop or onDestroy didn't work ?

Comment: Yes, `removeCallbacksAndMessages` in onStop/onDestroy didn't work, but `removeCallbacks` in onStop/onDestroy did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should use `removeCallbacks()`, not `removeCallbacksAndMessages()`

also it seems that you have pending `Runnables` that you should remove when your `Activity` says "bye bye", so try to call `removeCallbacks()` in `onPause` / `onStop` / `onDestroy`